# Removing file handle from cURL (CURLOPT_FILE)

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface

For my cURL resource in PHP CLI, I have set a file stream as to where the downloaded content should be saved to, with the help of `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FILE, $handle)`, where $handle is valid file resource where I can write to.

Now I would like to reuse the same curl resource, clear the file handle so I can execute the curl requests and capture the output with output buffering.

I've read that you're supposed to do `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FILE, STDOUT)`, but the problem with that is that it bypasses the output buffer, and any request I execute is output to my cli and is not capturable by output buffering.
I also tried closing the file handle, but that just made the responses disappear into void.

So does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true, that should override writing into a file

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
```

To get headers

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle , CURLOPT_HEADER , true);
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
list($header , $data) = explode("\r\n\r\n" , $result , 2);
```

Comment: May I also ask what I can do to get the headers of a response as well and separate it from the body?