# cURL and curl_setopt- how to remove an option

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL to firstly get a list of files from a remote FTP server. I then use the same Curl Handle to download that file. After the download, I then once again use the same handle to remove the file.

When I use the following code to remove the file, it does succeed:

```
curl_setopt($tmp["curl"], CURLOPT_QUOTE, array("DELE " . $tmp["file"]));
```

although I get the following in the logs:

```
[PHP Warning] curl_exec(): CURLOPT_FILE resource has gone away, resetting to default [l:52]
```

The reason is that when I first downloaded the file, I set the following option:

```
curl_setopt($tmp["curl"], CURLOPT_FILE, $tmp["file_handle"]);
```

My question is, how do I unset options that I have added? I want to remove the above option so that I can reuse the curl connection to delete the file.. or what option to I set to basically unset this option?

Answer (score 5):

You unset an option by setting the value to `null`, like so:

```
curl_setopt($tmp["curl"], CURLOPT_QUOTE, null);
```

Comment: Hmm this didnt work. The file removes successfully..but still getting PHP notices: [Dec 09 21:13:20]  warning: [PHP Warning] curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource [l:51]
[Dec 09 21:13:20]  warning: [PHP Warning] curl_exec(): CURLOPT_FILE resource has gone away, resetting to default [l:53]

Comment: This does not set the defaults, there is no way to do it.
That call might cause invalid results in some cases. 
In other cases it will cause a fatal error (like headers or a file handle)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to use the same curl instance to save to a file, then request a page and save to a variable.

After trying all of the above and other suggestions, none of which worked, I came accross the correct solution....

reset file to default STDOUT

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, fopen('php://stdout','w'));
```

dont' forget to re-enable return transfer if that's what you want to do

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
curl_setopt($tmp["curl"], CURLOPT_FILE, STDOUT);
```

Comment: It doesn't remove it from request headers, it only set it to null.

Answer (score 1):

just setting it to `NULL` should work

```
curl_setopt($tmp["curl"], CURLOPT_FILE, NULL);
```

as discussed here

http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2012-03/0082.html

Answer (score 1):

If you [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251829/removing-file-handle-from-curl-curlopt-file), as well, basically reset the CURLOPT_FILE option to the default STDOUT (NULL will cause a warning!).

Then, if you mean to capture the output to a string, you need to explicitly set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option to true to override the file option, even if you set it earlier on.

Hope this helps somebody who was also looking for this answer.