# Redirect php output (cli) opens many file handles

Tags: php, file, curl

I have a long running (complex) php script that is run from the command line:

`php myscript.php 2> myscript.err.out > myscript.out &`

For some reasone this opens many (system-level) file handles - i.e. `lsof | grep myscript.out | wc -l` is increasing until hitting the limit.

Of course one could increase the limit (via `ulimit`), but I really need to find the cause as there should actually be only one file handle open to that file. (I.e. increasing would only delay the problem)

As I couldn't trim down to a minimal example - here some characteristics:

- The number of open files strongly correlates with the following two actions:

  - Opens (and closes!) temporary files (via `tempnam`)
  - Stores these temporary files in MongoDB
- System: SMP Debian 3.14.15-2

Has anyone an idea? (Or some things I could try?)

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what all things in your code may open files, sockets, named pipes, etc. or access devices as would be listed with `lsof`

Comment: But as I don't open a file named myscript.out inside my script, that should not influence the grep on lsof. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many more trys I could drill down the problem to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
```

This was done in a loop (as the curl instance was reused - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786481/curl-and-curl-setopt-how-to-remove-an-option)).

So the solution is: store the handle to stdout and close it:

```
if (isset($stdout) && is_resource($stdout)) {
  fclose($stdout);
}
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $stdout)
```

**Note:** you should *not* reuse `$stdout` directly but always close and open it again! (You'll get messed up output!)